# Derivation of Newtons Method from Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

I want to derive Newton’s method from a second order Taylor approximation of the objective function.

So starting from the Taylor expansion: 
$f ^ { k } ( x ) = f \left( x ^ { k } \right) + \nabla f \left( x ^ { k } \right) ^ { T } \left( x - x ^ { k } \right) + \frac { 1} { 2} \left( x - x ^ { k } \right) ^ { T } \nabla ^ { 2} f \left( x ^ { k } \right) \left( x - x ^ { k } \right)$

I am computing the derivative w.r.t. to x and set it to 0, which should give:

$ \nabla f \left( x ^ { k } \right) + \nabla ^ { 2} f \left( x ^ { k } \right) \left( x - x ^ { k } \right) = 0 $

The derivatives for the first to terms are clear to me,
for the third term I know I can rewrite it in the following form:

$\frac { 1} { 2} \left( x - x ^ { k } \right) ^ { T } \nabla ^ { 2} f \left( x ^ { k } \right) \left( x - x ^ { k } \right) = \frac { 1} { 2}
\nabla ^ { 2} f \left( x ^ { k } \right) \left( x - x ^ { k } \right)^2 $

Which also clearly gives me the right solution.

However starting from:

$\frac { 1} { 2} \left( x - x ^ { k } \right) ^ { T } \nabla ^ { 2} f \left( x ^ { k } \right) \left( x - x ^ { k } \right)$

Shouldn't I also be able to calculate the derivative using the following 
rule:

> For the special case where A is a symmetric matrix and
>
> $ \alpha = x^T A x $
>
> where x is n×1, A is n×n, and A does not depend on x, then
>
> $ \frac { \partial \alpha } { \partial x } = 2x ^ { T } A $

To my understanding this would give me:

$  \left( x - x ^ { k } \right)^T\nabla ^ { 2} f \left( x ^ { k } \right) $

Which clearly has dimension: $1 \times n$
instead of $n \times 1$ and therefore clearly seems not right to me.

So where is the error in my thinking?

Comment: The gradient is best identified as a row vector, since its main purpose is to map column vectors to scalars (through the directional derivative).

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I do not really get the relation to my question here?

Comment: I'm saying that 1xn is the shape you should expect. Writing the gradient as nx1 is really an abuse of notation.

Comment: Are you looking at $n=1$? If not, how can you write $\left( x - x ^ { k } \right)^2$?